# Which common communication protocol to use for communicating with a java layer in a web architecuture

Tags: java, php, architecture, protocols, communication

[image: architecture that I am planning]

I am planning to design such an architecture for my website as shown in picture above. I am building a core platform in Java that do the communication with DB and other high processing tasks and modules can hook up with the core by means of defined interfaces.

Modules could be anything like, front-end website, email box, admin consoles etc. and could be built on any technology like PHP, Java, ruby on rails etc.

Now tell me which communication protocol should I use for communication between modules and core. Protocol must be something that majority of languages understand and can be process easily in both way communication.

And if somebody find any flaws with such an architecture then kindly suggest a better one that provide great extensibility and flexibility.

Comment: HTTP API, maybe REST, maybe JSON.

Comment: @Thilo which is best to use out of them in such a design? in terms of processing requirement and complexity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use HTTP, exposing a REST API on the Core, such as Thilo suggested.

The complexity lies on the trade-offs between RPC (procedural model) of traditional webservices, and the Resource Model, which fits better when using http requests (verbs GET, POST, PUT and DELETE on URI's, complemented with some headers and a body).

Yet, this makes a soft, easy to maitain and portable ditribution. Every single client module may be built on a whole different technology, which allows you to use "the best tool for the job".

Not to mention HTTP advantages for caching, rewriting, load-balancing, ssl, etc.

Comment: And HTTP has very good support on all platforms and languages.

Comment: @user1526281 and which rest api do you think suits best in this environment in java side. As I am new to it, I have to go through it first, so tell me with which should I go.

Comment: I'm not aware of the options on the Java platform. I use OpenRasta or Nancy in .Net, and I know Sinatra on the Ruby platform (which Nancy was based on).

Answer (score 3):

So basically this is a SOA-like architekture. JavaEE and EJB (3+) or the Spring frameworks come to mind immediately.

The components (your "modules") are usually coupled via SOAP services with an optional  Enterprise Service Bus (ESB) between frontend, backend and the composite services.

Whether this is a good match for your case or simply oversized... noone but you can say...

Comment: yeah I am looking for a SOA, can you clarify more how you mean to achieve this especially I didn't got what you said in second para?  or give me some knowledge sources for this?